# Animate Jquery slider from out side of the Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

this slider is slide to left and right. I like to trigger this slider from outside of the slider.

how to slide left and right,using another #left and #right buttons from out side of the slider.

this slider has two way triggering system. one is section vice and other is link wise. i need to trigger both ways from out side divs. (# left and #right)

[Check here slider](http://tympanus.net/Development/TripleViewLayout/)

```
  $("#left").click(function (e) {
    $(".vs-nav-left").trigger("click");
});

$("#right").click(function (e) {
    $(".vs-nav-right").trigger("click");
});
```

i tried with this code. but its not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in main.js

```
$("#left").click(function (e) {  
    navigate( 'left' );  
});  

$("#right").click(function (e) {  
    navigate( 'right' );  
});
```

Hopefully it works..